# PostgreSQL : Aggregate multiple rows from a table into a single record

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I need to aggregate multiple rows in a table into a single record using an SQL query. Below is the table structure and the required output details,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mind you asking this, whom this is required by?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic pivot query requirement.  On Postgres, we can try:

```sql
SELECT id, name,
       'english' AS subject1,
       MAX(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'english') AS marks1,
       'math' AS subject2,
       MAX(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'math') AS marks2,
       'science' AS subject3,
       MAX(marks) FILTER (WHERE subject = 'science') AS marks3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id, name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo